# Why does pyspark's BinaryClassificationEvaluator avgMetrics returns a value larger than one?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

```
    evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator()
    grid = ParamGridBuilder().build()  # no hyper parameter optimization
    cv = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline, estimatorParamMaps=grid, evaluator=evaluator)
    cvModel = cv.fit(dataset)
    evaluator.evaluate(cvModel.transform(dataset))
```

Returns:

- `cvModel.avgMetrics = [1.602872634746238]`
- `evaluator.evaluate(cvModel.transform(dataset)) = 0.7267754950388204`

Questions:

1. How can avgMetric be larger than 1 (1.6) if it is area under ROC?
2. Is the scheme evaluator.evaluate(cvModel.transform(dataset)) actually returns the training metric and not the cross validation metric? (we used `dataset` both for fit and evaluate)

Answer (score 5):

It is a bug that has been [fixed](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/639df046a250873c26446a037cb832ab28cb5272) recently. However, it is not released yet.

Based on what you provided, I used the following code to replicate the issue:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder, CrossValidator
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.sql.types import Row

dataset = sc.parallelize([
    Row(features=Vectors.dense([1., 0.]), label=1.),
    Row(features=Vectors.dense([1., 1.]), label=0.),
    Row(features=Vectors.dense([0., 0.]), label=1.),
]).toDF()

evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(metricName="areaUnderROC")
grid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid('maxIter', [100, 10]).build()  # no hyper parameter optimization
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=LogisticRegression(), estimatorParamMaps=grid, evaluator=evaluator)
cvModel = cv.fit(dataset)
evaluator.evaluate(cvModel.transform(dataset))

Out[23]: 1.0

cvModel.avgMetrics

Out[34]: [2.0, 2.0]
```

Simply put,

> `avgMetrics` was summed, not averaged, across folds

EDIT:

About the second question, the easiest way to validate is to supply a test dataset:

```
to_test = sc.parallelize([
    Row(features=Vectors.dense([1., 0.]), label=1.),
    Row(features=Vectors.dense([1., 1.]), label=0.),
    Row(features=Vectors.dense([0., 1.]), label=1.),
]).toDF()

evaluator.evaluate(cvModel.transform(to_test))

Out[2]: 0.5
```

It confirms the function call returns the metrics on the test dataset.

Comment: Thanks, can you please respond to the second bullet? Is the scheme evaluator.evaluate(cvModel.transform(dataset)) actually returns the training metric and not the cross validation metric? (we used dataset both for fit and evaluate)

Comment: Please see my edit. You shouldn't use the dataset for train/validation.

Comment: the *same* dataset :)

Comment: One of the main advantages of cross-validation is that you should be able to estimate average test error without holding out a separate validation set (many times you don't have the luxury of having enough data to do this). If you randomly select a holdout set, then your estimate of error can be highly biased. Better to have access to the cross-validation error on each of the k hold out sets.

Comment: @EvanZamir yea i was confused by Spark's demo code showing CV and testing it against a holdout set.  Usually you use one or the other, right?  Each fold has its own holdout set.